# How to Share a Contact in Microsoft Outlook using EWS .NET API

Tags: .net, outlook, exchange-server, contacts, exchangewebservices

I want (as the title says) to share a contact using Exchange Webservice .NET API. I have this code to save the contact:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("Barack Obama", "1234");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("obama@gmail.com");

Contact contact = new Contact(service);
contact.GivenName = "Michelle LaVaughn";
contact.Surname = "Robinson Obama";
contact.JobTitle = "My Wife";

contact.Save(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts));
```

Then, i just copy the contact to other Outlook user with this code:

```
contact.Copy(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, "co-worker@gmail.com"));
```

My problem is: They are not really the same contact! Two different ID's. If i edit one of them the other one does not get the modification. I can actually share contacts or a contact folder with Microsoft Outlook but i don't know how to do it with the API.

My question is: How can i share that contact with my co-workers and being able to edit it so they can see the modification ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a public folder and then Move or Copy the contact into the shared folder. See [Public folder access with EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945067%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).